# Using Inclusion-Exclusion, probability of occurrence of exactly $m$ events out of $\{A_1,\cdots,A_n\}$

Tags: probability

Using Inclusion-Exclusion, prove that the probability of occurrence of exactly $m$ events out of $\{A_1,\cdots,A_n\} = \sum_{i=0}^{n-m} ~  (-1)^i   \binom{m+i}{m} P_{m+i} $ where $P_{k} = \sum_{1 \leq i_1<\cdots i_k \leq n} P(A_{i_1} \bigcap\cdots \bigcap A_{i_k})$

**Attempt:**  I was trying to understand this term on the RHS : $\binom{m+i}{m} P_{m+i}$. And then the inclusion-exclusion principle shall follow.

**This is what I thought to be able to use inclusion-exclusion but I am not very sure if this is the right approach.**

$m$ events can occur either from the first $m$ events, or from the first $m+1$ events, or from the first $m+2$ events, $\cdots$, or from the n events.

$$E_k = \text{the m events occur from the first m+k events}$$

Then $P(E_k) = \binom{m+k}{m} \sum_{1\leq i_1<\cdots i_m\leq m+k} P(A_{i_1} \bigcap \cdots  \bigcap A_{i_m})$

But, then I could not move forward from here. I tried understanding the solution given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716775/the-probability-p-m-that-exactly-m-among-the-n-events-a-1-dots-a-n), but I would really appreciate something more intuitive.

Could someone please explain how do I move forward from here?

Comment: Are the events $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$ mutually exclusive?

Comment: @mhdadk not necessarily

Comment: You might find it algebraically pleasing--and simpler--to work with the indicator functions of the $A_i.$